# SearchBar of UISearchController is lying under statusbar when it actives( ios 9.3 ,ios 8.4)

Tags: swift3, ios10, uisearchcontroller

[image]

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ProductSearch_iPhone", bundle: nil)
   let controller : RSearchResultController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SResult") 
                                              as! RSearchResultController

    searchController                        = UISearchController(searchResultsController:controller)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater   = controller
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation   = true
    controller.delegate                                 = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate                 = controller
    self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

I've added UISearchController by not integrated with UITableview like many Other tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.The issue was not device specific, ios 9 and ios8 shows wrecked design while in ios10 it is fine.

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

The above line of code was the issue, which was written on the intention *searchbar* should not be there when i navigate to somewhere & comeback while *UISearchController* is active. But according to my requirement i have no choice of navigation when *UISearchController* is active.